# WordPress Site Having Fatal Error in Root View

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

I have running WordPress Site but now a error occurs when I login to Admin Panel of WordPress and site is also not live now. A 'Fatal Error' is showing:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class WP_Theme_Handler_Checker in /home/niteshvyas84/public_html/shreejeeexcellency.restaurant/wp-content/themes/resca/inc/theme-checker.php on line 4
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or do I have to uninstall WordPress and start from scratch?

Comment: In your hosting account’s control panel, navigate to /wp-content/themes/ and rename the directory of your currently active theme. This will force the default theme to activate so you can use your site.  Then check the error into your themes old functioning call

Comment: Thanks a lot, I rename the Theme in root directory and then Delete it and re-Extract it in root directory and My Site now live and also WordPress Dashboard shown too but When I visit site a Dangerous message shown like phishing site and I am click on "Click on Unsafe Visit" then my site shown and a Dangerous message shown in Browser. So I can  I solve this now , please help to fully protect it and live it. @RajKumarBhardwaj

Comment: http://imgur.com/C2ylkjd @RajKumarBhardwaj

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your theme somewhere. If you have another theme installed (but obviously inactive), use [this guide](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/change-theme-in-db) to change your theme to something else while you troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your theme.  Connect to your site's FTP server and move the folder wp-content/themes/resca to another folder (such as the root) or download and then delete it.  You should then be able to log into the backend and set another theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening `theme-checker.php` file and then wrap the class declaration code with the `class_exists()` function, something like:

```
if ( !class_exists( 'WP_Theme_Handler_Checker' ) {
//The existing class declaration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Best Solution which really works For Me

I add My Website in Google Search Console after Website Ownership Verify, I see the same Malware attack message with full details in Website Security option in Search Console Dashboard. Then I submit request to Google look into this web page and do the necessary task. After submitting the, request in review and within 48 hours I got mail from Search Console that your Affected Malware attack hacked website successfully reviewed and Malware was removed successfully from your root directory too. Now No Dangerous message shown in Google Chrome visiting your Site but it still take few hour too. Overall in Max 72 hours the website Ready and no Treats shown and no Dangerous message shown in Chrome Now. Thanks to Google Search Console.